# Помогите, пожалуйста, с рекурсивной функцией на js

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

```js
function Define(i) {
  if (i == 0)
    return 0;
  if (i == 1)
    return 1;
  else
    return (i - 1) * (i + 2) - i / (i - 1);
}
```

Задача в том, чтобы написать рекурсивную функцию, определяющую n-ный элемент ряда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать рекурсивную функцию?
и что вообще должно быть в аргументах функции?

Comment: Ты точно не путаешь рекурсивную функцию с рекуррентной формулой?

Comment: @Qwertiy да, в этом и была моя ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pекурсивная функция содержит вызов себя.

В аргументах должен быть номер члена последовательности.

Уверен, теперь сможете написать.

```js
function Define(i) {
  if (i == 0)
    return 0;
  else if (i == 1)
    return 1;
  else
    return Define(i - 1) * (i + 2) - i / Define(i - 1);
}

for (var j = 0; j <= 10; j++)
  console.log(Define(j));
```

Comment: @loreley Почти. Там, где у Вас `(i - 1)`, должен быть вызов функции.

Comment: Всё, поняла, спасибо большое)

Comment: @loreley На здоровье. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.